# Solvable Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $g=A+B$ be a Lie algebra, where $A,B$ are metabelian algebras. Is $g$ solvable?
By definition, an algebra $A$ is metabelian if $A\prime$ is abelian, where $A\prime=[A,A]$ .

Answer (score 0):

No: for $V=\mathbf{C}^2$ the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is the sum of the Lie algebra $A$ of upper triangular matrices and the Lie algebra $B$ of lower triangular matrices, both of which are metabelian.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is not correct for your definition of metabelian (although the sum of two solvable *ideals* is again solvable). However, there is another definition of "metabelian" in the literature, saying that a metabelian Lie algebra is a $2$-step nilpotent Lie algebra. For a discussion see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139149/when-did-the-meaning-of-the-term-metabelian-change). Goto proved that any Lie algebra $$L=A+B,$$ which is the sum of two *nilpotent* subalgebras, is solvable (see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.3113)).